# Can't run ArrayFire helloworld example under OS X 10.9

Tags: macos, arrayfire

I downloaded and installed the following packages under MAC OS X 10.9:

> ArrayFire-maci-1.9-20121120.zip
>
> cuda-mac-5.5.28_10.9_64.pkg

After successful building the helloworld example I get the following output:

> ```
> c++  -m64 -Wall -Werror -I../../include -I/usr/local/cuda/include -O3 -DNDEBUG -L../../lib -laf -lafGFX -L/usr/local/cuda/lib -lcuda -lcudart -lcurand -lcusparse -lpthread -lstdc++ -lm -Wl,-rpath,../../lib,-rpath,/opt/arrayfire/lib,-rpath,/usr/local/cuda/lib
> ```
>
> helloworld.cpp   -o helloworld

However when trying to run the helloworld executable I get the following error:

> ```
> ./helloworld 
> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libcufft.5.5.dylib
>   Referenced from: /opt/arrayfire/lib/libaf.dylib
>   Reason: Incompatible library version: libaf.dylib requires version 5.5.0 or later, but libcufft.5.5.dylib provides version 0.0.0
> Trace/BPT trap: 5
> ```

But the version of the dylib library is correct according to the otool output:

> ```
> otool -L /usr/local/cuda/lib/libcufft.dylib
> libcufft.dylib:       @rpath/libcufft.5.5.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 5.5.28)     /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.1.0)
> ```
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 635.21.0)
> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 52.0.0)

Does anybody have ideas how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH in your .bash_profile

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$AF_PATH/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$CUDA_PATH/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```